# AWS - moving RDS to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc

We have couple of RDS that are not added under VPC, so we need to bring them under VPC. Please let me know the steps and downtime expected. Also let me know if there need to be any changes in the webservers, so that everything works fine after RDS is under VPC.

Answer (score 7):

You must have a VPC created before hand that have subnet in atleast two different regions.

After this go and create a  "subnet group" for RDS and add two existing subnet in that.

Next take a snapshot of your RDS instance and start a new RDS instance from snapshot in VPC.

That should be it.

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.html#USER_VPC.Non-VPC2VPC - official documentation from Amazon.

Comment: The documentation has moved or perhaps just been expanded since this answer was given. Try this link: [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Non-VPC2VPC](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Non-VPC2VPC)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your configuration and if the RDS needs to be accessible from the Internet you will have to check the option "Publicly Accessible" in the creation wizard and (in addition to the subnets mentioned in other answers) ensure that the Security has port for the DB properly enabled (and maybe from 0.0.0.0/0).